# c++ windows application edit the main window

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create a simple windows application in cpp. Opening Visual Studio 2019, I noticed that there is, in fact, a project like that, so I opened up a new one.[image]

This is the window I get when I run it. Completely normal, as expected from a brand new project.

But... I can't figure out how to edit the main window? When I go into the project rc directory, there's options to edit everything else. Add new dialogue boxes, add proper gui to them, edit the top bar with new options, etc. Does anyone know where is the gui for editing the main window?

Comment: It's probably drawn programatically in something like "WinProc"

Comment: Is there a way to edit it with a GUI as well?

Comment: Not the main window. You can create a dialog, which can be done with a GUI/.rc file, and use that as your main window. Or maybe use something like [Qt](https://www.qt.io/).

Comment: In the premade project, the main window is generated from code, not from a template. You can create a dialog template and use the dialog as your main window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Right click on your project and **Add resource** -> **Dialog**.

`IDD_DIALOG1` is created by default.

2.Modify the code in `InitInstance()` :

```
 HWND hWnd = CreateDialog(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), GetDesktopWindow(), (DLGPROC)WndProc);
```

3.There is  a `IDD_DIALOG1` in the Resource View and it can be edited by double click.

Comment: Hi, @ArchSinccubus  May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: I did. It's no longer relevant now, but thank you for the answer all the same.